# How to run spinner in Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

How can we run spinner in while Axios is requesting to the API?

I have added a bootstrap spinner in my HTML and in the js file, I have set it to `none` property.

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner-grow text-info" role="status">
    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

How can I set the `block` while it's requesting to the API once the request completed set its property again to `none`

```
document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none';
axios.post(`/getData/users/pagewise`,data)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                const $recievedHTML = $(response.data);
                $("#View").replaceWith($recievedHTML);

            })
            .catch(error => {
               console.log(error);
               console.log(error.response.data);
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do just that: Set `block` before doing the call, and `none` when the call is complete (probably using a `finally` handler):

```
document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'block';
axios.post(`/getData/users/pagewise`,data)
    .then(response => {
       console.log(response);
       const $recievedHTML = $(response.data);
       $("#View").replaceWith($recievedHTML);

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.response.data);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none';
    });
```

You might consider using a class instead of directly manipulating the style.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the axios.post request make it `display: block`, and when the promise resolves make it `display: none` again.